# How to make jQuery AutoComplete function work in Durandal?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, durandal

I'm adding `autoComplete` functionality in a existing Durandal app.
I've declared the jQuery-UI lib in the main.js and in my component.
I've built a test-array with values to feed the AutoComplete widget (a console.log shows that this array has value in it).
I've set a hold point near the AutoComplete function and I can see the app passing in when `document.ready` function triggers.
When I try to input some letters in the input field, no values are displayed.
What did I forget ?

Here is my HTML (just a part) :

```
<!-- Operation ID -->
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-4" data-bind="text:props.getProperty('label.search.operation.id')"></label>
    <div class="col-xs-8">
        <input type="text" id="operationID" data-bind="value: model.filter().operationID, click: advancedSearch" class="form-control" autocomplete=on />
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the corresponding JS file (part), function can be seen at the end of file :

```
define(['durandal/app', 'knockout', 'jquery', 'services/propertiesService', 'utils/dateUtils', 'jquery-ui'],
    function(app, ko, $, props, dateUtils, ui) {

        var model = {};

        model.trackedObjects = [];
        model.successes = ko.observableArray();
        model.errors = ko.observableArray();
        model.warnings = ko.observableArray();

        model.currencies = ko.observableArray([]);
        model.buyers = ko.observableArray([]);
        model.platforms = ko.observableArray([]);
        model.steps = ko.observableArray([]);
        model.operationTypes = ko.observableArray([]);
        model.counterparts = ko.observableArray([]);

        model.choosenRoleCode = ko.observableArray();
        model.resultCount = ko.observable(0);

        // .................................
        // Many other properties

        //Set the button 'Go on top' if the scrolling is not on top of the window
        $(window).scroll(function(event) {
            var st = $(this).scrollTop();
            if (st > 0) {
                //On top
                model.hasScrollbar(true);
            } else {
                model.hasScrollbar(false);
            }
        });
        /* _____________________ENDING - Scroll bar____________________ */

        // AUTOCOMPLETE : Fill OperationID with values
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var availableTags = [
                "TOTO",
                "TITI",
                "TUTU"
            ];
            console.log("hop : " + availableTags); // hop : TOTO,TITI,TUTU
            $("#operationID").autocomplete({
                source: availableTags
            });
        });

        return model;
    })
```

Has anybody already encountered this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should move all the jQuery functionality inside the Lifecycle callback named [`compositionComplete`](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Interacting-with-the-DOM.html#compositioncomplete). This function is executed *after* the entire view is composed and `operationID` is available on the DOM

```
define(['durandal/app', 'knockout', 'jquery', 'services/propertiesService', 
       'utils/dateUtils', 'jquery-ui'],
  function(app, ko, $, props, dateUtils, ui) {

    var model = {};

    model.trackedObjects = [];
    model.successes = ko.observableArray();
    model.errors = ko.observableArray();
    model.warnings = ko.observableArray();

    // ........

    model.compositionComplete: function() {
      var availableTags = ["TOTO", "TITI", "TUTU"];

      $("#operationID").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
      });

      $(window).scroll(function(event) {
        var st = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (st > 0) {
          //On top
          model.hasScrollbar(true);
        } else {
          model.hasScrollbar(false);
        }
      });
    }

    return model;
  })
```

Comment: You are right. I noticed the conflict between the Durandal "compositionComplete" lifecycle stage and the jQuery $(document).ready statement.
Now this point is OK, I have to face a new problem -> I've changed my test tags (TITI, TOTO...) with the result of an Ajax asynchron query but no values are displayed...
I often wander why we are using this framework instead of pure ECMA or jQuery ^^

Thanx for your time and help